# Eclipse marks entire JNI c code function on android as method could not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am using Gstreamer tutorial code and Eclipse does not find any functions („method could not be resolved“ error).
It seems that Eclipse has no way to determine methods, even they are clearly in includes.
My Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tutorial-3
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := tutorial-3.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := gstreamer_android
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT
ifndef GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID
$(error GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID is not defined!)
endif
GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT        := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_ANDROID)
endif
GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH  := $(GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT)/share/gst-android/ndk-build/
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/plugins.mk
GSTREAMER_PLUGINS         := $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_CORE) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_SYS) $(GSTREAMER_PLUGINS_EFFECTS)
GSTREAMER_EXTRA_DEPS      := gstreamer-interfaces-0.10 gstreamer-video-0.10
include $(GSTREAMER_NDK_BUILD_PATH)/gstreamer.mk
```

It does not work with any built-in lib, like pthread and android/log  and for some bizarre reason does not find any functions only typedefs and not struct internals. I tried reindexing, tried cleaning it just do not disappear. Funny thing is that it builds and compiles without errors only editor sees them. 
I can click proper headers and they expose methods related to functions.

Is there anything I can do to make it work? NDK is needed for me.

**Update:**

I took deeper look in my problem. Include paths seems to be right. Under left side in project pane and in properties I see them. It finds typedefs just right. It finds function not referenced by struct too. problems starts with macros ant structs with pointers to functions.

Even built-in JNI functions fails:

```
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, version_utf8); //method NewStringUTF not found
```

Even more when I convert .c file to .cpp and change methods which I can to c++ form:

```
(env)->NewStringUTF(env, version_utf8); //now OK
```

Now it finds them.
Also Macroses fails:

```
 __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "tutorial-1", "Could not retrieve JNIEnv"); // symbol ANDROID_LOG_ERROR could not be found
```

Include path are OK (`right click jni folder -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Includes`), but `right click jni folder -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Includes` are blanked out, entries tab is empty.

Comment: Did you update the Eclipse project properties for your Defines or include paths?  While Eclipse will compile via your provided makefile, it doesn't leverage its information within the IDE.  All of that information( -D defines, -I include paths, etc ) is within your c++ project properties

Comment: This is a well-know and long-running Eclipse indexing bug. :(

Comment: Include paths seems to be right. Under left side in project pane and in properties I see them. It finds typedefs just right. It finds function not referenced by struct too. problems starts with macros ant structs with pointers.

Comment: Samhain I updated question, what I found.